# Automorphism with Projection

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given the following problem for homework. It's taken from Golan's book on linear algebra. I've spent some time on it but can't link $\gamma
$ with $\beta$ to generate a solution. I would really be grateful if someone could assist.
 "$V$ is vector space of finite dimension $n$ over field $F$. Let $\alpha\in$ End (V). Prove existence of an automorphism $\beta$ of $V$ and a projection $\gamma$ of $V$ such that $\alpha=\beta\gamma$.

Comment: What is $\theta$ ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should read $\alpha=\beta\gamma$

Comment: Noted. In view of the answers received, I agree with you that the statement is of no value. It has been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$V_\alpha = \alpha(V) = \text{Range}(\alpha) \subseteq V; \tag 1$

since

$\dim V = n < \infty, \tag 2$

we also have

$m = \dim V_\alpha < \infty; \tag 3$

if

$m = n, \tag 4$

then

$V_\alpha = V; \tag 5$

in this case we may take

$\beta = \alpha, \; \gamma = I, \tag 6$

and we are done.

When

$m < n, \tag 7$

we have

$V_\alpha \subsetneq V; \tag 8$

we then choose a basis

$v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m \in V_\alpha \tag 9$

of $V_\alpha$, and by choosing $n - m$ linearly independent vectors

$v_{m + 1}, v_{m + 2}, \ldots, v_n \in V \setminus V_\alpha \tag{10}$

extend the set $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m \}$ to a basis $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m, \ldots, v_n \}$ of $V$.

We may now define $\beta$ and $\gamma$ as follows:  any

$v \in V \tag{11}$

may be uniquely written as

$v = \displaystyle \sum_1^n c_iv_i,  \; c_i \in F, 1 \le i \le n; \tag{12}$

we thus set

$\gamma(v) = \displaystyle \sum_1^m c_iv_i \in V_\alpha; \tag{13}$

it is easy to see that

$\gamma^2 = \gamma, \tag{14}$

that is, $\gamma$ is a projection onto $V_\alpha$.  As for $\beta$, 
we take

$\beta(v) = \alpha(v), \; \forall v \in V_\alpha, \tag{15}$

and

$\beta \left ( \displaystyle \sum_{m + 1}^n c_iv_i \right ) =  \displaystyle \sum_{m + 1}^n c_iv_i, \tag{16}$

and extend $\beta$ by linearity to all of $V$:

$\beta \left ( \displaystyle \sum_1^n c_i v_i \right ) = \beta \left (\displaystyle \sum_1^m c_i v_i \right ) + \displaystyle \sum_{m + 1}^n c_i v_i = \alpha \left (\sum_1^n c_i v_i \right ) + \sum_{m + 1}^n c_i v_i. \tag{16.5}$

It is easy to see that $\beta$ is an automorphism of $V$; indeed, $\beta$ is an automorphism of $V_\alpha$, since by (1) and (15)

$\beta: V_\alpha \to V_\alpha \tag{17}$

is manifestly surjective; but a surjective linear map on a vector space of finite dimension is also injective; thus $\beta$ restriced to $V_\alpha$ is an automorphism; furthermore, (16) shows that $\beta$
is the identity mapping on $\text{span}\{v_{m + 1}, v_{m + 2}, \ldots, v_n \}$; these two observations taken in concert show that $\beta$ is an automorphism of $V$; finally, for any $v \in V$ we have

$\beta \gamma(v) = \alpha(v), \tag{18}$

since $\gamma(v) \in V_\alpha$ and $\beta \equiv \alpha$ on $V_\alpha$ (15).  $OE\Delta$.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed response. I would never have reasoned this solution.

Comment: @Sylvia:  thanks for the kind words.  You might consider upvoting/accepting my answer if you really like it.  Cheers!

Comment: Done. Upvoted. I'm new to this site so don't know the protocols.

Comment: @Sylvia:  thanks for the ***+1***, and thanks for the "acceptance"!  It's cosidered "polite" around here to give those who have helped you (by answering) some help in the form of upvotes/acceptance.  Of course, you have the right/responsibility to vote in accord with your true response, but it's also good to allow gratitude to come into play.  It'll help *you* to be known as one who "pays" your "workers".  Thanks again!  Cheers!

Comment: @Sylvia:  I think the key is realizing $V_\alpha = \alpha(V)$ is an $\alpha$-invariant subspace!  Cheers again!

Answer (score 1):

Stealing your homework is not mine, but let me state a hint for a possible start:

Just take the assumed automorphism $\beta$ to write
$\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha\,=\,\gamma,$
then analyse

- $\ker\gamma\subset V$, the kernel of the projection: How does it depend on
  the given $\alpha\in\operatorname{End}(V)\,$?
- the complementary subspace $\{v\in V\mid \gamma(v)=v\}$ to $\ker\gamma$.
  It is called the "support" of the projection, and you may denote it by $\operatorname{supp}\gamma\,$.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Although Robert Lewis has also supplied a detailed solution (as above), I shall use your hints in an attempt to understand the solution further. I do appreciate your assistance.

Comment: And thank you @Sylvia for your kind comment + +1. In striving for a more thorough understanding you may ask + analyse if $\beta$ is uniquely determined by $\alpha$? And the projection $\gamma$? Projections, aka projectors or idempotents, are important building blocks in the realm of linear operators, a good understanding of them is worthwhile!